# Registering 32 and 64 bit DLL in a single MSI using WiX

Tags: windows, dll, wix, 64-bit, 32-bit

I need to create a SINGLE Windows installer that performs the following tasks when it is run on the target m/c:

- Runs a service
- Registers a 32 bit DLL
- Stores the 32 bit and 64 bit log4cxx.dll libraries in `C:\Windows\sysWoW64` folder and `C:\Windows\system32`
- Registers a 64 bit DLL

Currently, I am using WiX to create an installer and I am at a point where I can register either 32 bit OR 64 bit installer but not both. Unfortunately, I don't have the option of separating the 32 and 64 bit installer as I need to register both the installers on a 64 bit machine.

I would like to know if there was a way to register both the DLLs in one installer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The normal way to do this is to have two separate .msi and a setup.exe bootstrapper that runs them both. And why are you writing to the system directories. You aren't meant to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am actually writing the log libraries to the system directories as the 32 and 64-bit DLLs use the log libraries for logging and they have to be in system directories. Could you recommend an approach to handle this in a correct way?

Comment: You aren't supposed to write anything to the system directories which are owned by the system. I see now reason why those DLLs need to live in system32

Comment: David, Can I just create a VS2008 SetUp Project and initiate the 2 .msi files from that? Actually I also need to start a service along with the .msi's. How do I do all three? And is it possible to do that using WiX (preferred than VS Setup Project)? I also want to vote your suggestion as answer, hot do I do that? Thanks for your help..

Comment: Like I said you would normally use a bootstrapper (e.g. setup.exe) to perform multiple msiexec commands. We use dotNetInstaller: http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/

Comment: You should not install any DLLs in system directories (which is known as [DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell)): put it next to your service executable.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to have the log DLLs in system directories as they need to be in user's path, so they can't reside with the service exe. Any other alternative?

Comment: @user591410 you should store the DLLs in a known location and load them from there. e.g. `c:\Program Files\Common Files\MyCorp\Shared` - not writing to system folders is one of the Windows Logo requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WiX doesn't support mixed 32/64-bit packages. So the only option is using separate packages:

1. A 32-bit package for 32-bit systems.
2. A 64-bit package which installs both 32-bit and 64-bit resources on a 64-bit machine.

Another solution is to use a different setup authoring tool which supports mixed 32/64-bit packages. Perhaps this list will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Comment: Okay.. I'll go ahead and make 2 separate packages. Unfortunately I cannot switch from WiX now. Thanks for the answer